# Python boolean operator membership test with integer enumerator

Tags: python, comparison, operator-keyword, operator-precedence, membership

i was testing the precedence of comparison and membership operator, as per Python documentation they are at same precedence. But it is showing strange results as follows,

If anyone can justify following code and the corresponding output..

```
print( ( True!= 12) in (12,14))  #output: False
print( True!= 12 in (12,14))  #output: True
print( True!= (12 in (12,14)))  #output: False
```

Answer (score 5):

From https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html:

> Note that **comparisons, membership tests, and identity tests, all have the same precedence and have a left-to-right chaining feature** as described in the [Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) section.

In the **Comparisons** section we find:

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y` and `y <= z`, except that `y` is evaluated only once (but in both cases `z` is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be false).

So, your second line is equivalent to:

```
True != 12 and 12 in (12, 14)
```

which evaluates to `True and True` which evaluates to `True`.

Similarly curious constructions are:

```
>>> True == True in (True, False)
True

>>> True == False in (True, False)
False

>>> 2 == 2 in (2, 3)
True

>>> 1 == 1 in (2, 3)
False

>>> 1 != 2 in (2, 3)
True

>>> 2 != 1 in (2, 3)
False

>>> 2 in (2, 3) in [True, False]
False
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have read the docs, but because of the common `x < y < z` example I wrongly thought the chaining feature only applied to ordering operators.

Comment: Thanks @progmatico! I agree that `x < y < z` seems like a "natural" thing. On the other hand, chaining inclusion test seems, at least to me, unnatural. For example, `2 in (2, 3) in [True, False]` does not return what I would expect (I will add this example to the oddity list).

Answer (score 3):

**First Case:**

```
print((True != 12) in (12,14))
```

We can say that first we evaluate `True != 12` condition which give us `True`, and then we are evaluating if `True` is in the tuple `(12,14)` and that's `False`.

**Third Case:**

```
print(True != (12 in (12,14)))
```

We can say that first we evaluate `(12 in (12,14))` condition which give us `True` because `12` is in the tuple `(12,14)`. Then we evaluate if `True != True` an that's `False`.

**Second Case:**

```
print( True != 12 in (12,14))
```

So here is the tricky one. Without the parentheses we don't have where to start evaluating the conditions. To explain this case, I'm gonna give you the next example: if you try the following code (which is pretty similar to the one that we are trying to figure out the result):

```
print(1 != 2 != 3) #output True
```

You are gonna get `True` and that's because `1 != 2` and `2 != 3`. So as you may have already noticed, it's an implicit `AND`. The above code is equal to:

```
print(1 != 2 and 2 != 3) #output True
```

So if we take this logic to our case, we are evaluating this:

```
print( True != 12 and 12 in (12,14)) # => (True and True) #output True
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Note that you should be using the `and` operator and not the bitwise `&`. Otherwise things might get worse: `1 & 2` is `0` while `1 and 2` is `2`.

Comment: You are right, I should use the `and` operator, I think I am more used to the `&` from other programming languages. Nevertheless, things don't get worse because relational operations take precedence over logical operation. So, `1 != 2` will give us `True` and `2 != 3` gives `True` and we end up with `True & True` = `True`.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Things would get worse to understand if someone  read your answer and starts using `&` as the `and` operator in Python. Of course I understood what you meant and it did not affect this particular case. I see you already fixed it, but we cannot upvote twice :)

Comment: Ahhh yes totally! It's ok, I'm not here for the points :D